# Pointwise convergence, continuity of limit function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, sequence-of-function

I'm self-studying from Abbott's Real Analysis. They begin with an attempt to prove that the pointwise limit of continuous functions is continuous, and show that it can't be done.

Assume $(f_n)$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ converging pointwise to limit $f$. Fix $c\in A$, and let $\epsilon >0$.

$|f(x) - f(c) \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(c)| + |f_n(c) - f(c)|$.

We can choose an $N$ such that $|f_N(c) - f(c)| < \epsilon /3$ because $(f_n) \to f$.

By continuity of $f_N$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that:
$|f_N(x) - f_N(c)| < \epsilon /3$
for all $x$ satisfying $|x-c|<\delta$.

But the problem is that we also need $|f_N(x) - f(x)| <\epsilon/3$ for all $x$ satisfying $|x-c| < \delta$.

It seems (naively), that we could have approached this differently and started with a $\delta$-ball around $c$ and then found the $N$ such that $|f_N(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon /3$ for any $x$ in the $\delta$-ball. Ie, for each $x$, there is some $N_x$ that works, by pointwise convergence, and then we just take $N=sup\{N_x: x\in \delta \text{-ball}\}$. Is the issue with this approach that this supremum might not exist, and that for any $N$, there is another $x$ that requires a larger $N$ for $|f_N(x) - f(x)|<\epsilon/3$ ?

Thank you, I'm just learning about sequence of functions so apologies for the basic question.

Comment: A supremum always exists in the sense it can just be +$\infty$, but you want your $N$ to be finite. Try to do this for the sequence $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ah, I see-- looking at the interval $(0,1)$, as we approach $1$, it takes a larger and larger $N_x$ to get $|f_{N_x}(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon $, and the $N$'s necessary for each $x$ in $(0,1)$ are not bounded above, which is why my idea doesn't work, right? Thank you very much for your response

Comment: I just read ahead a section-- it looks like a uniformly convergent sequence of functions gets around this issue since there is an $N$ that works for all $x\in A$.